# Can I reduce this AC motor speed?

Tags: motor, speed

I spent yesterday opening this fan unit and researching...

I'm looking to reduce the speed by about 25-40%, at the lowest speed setting only.

Please have a look at the photo and let me know what options I have?

Fyi the resistance values is 190, 260, 310

I would prefer not to do the light bulb trick if possible.

Please advise.

Much appreciated

Thanks guys

[image: Motor Pic]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not allowed to offer or accept money on this site...

Comment: Anyway, if this is a synchronous motor, you can't change its speed. If it's an induction motor, you can.

Comment: https://www.imgurupload.com/uploads/20210123/d56dc5301ffc4ef002d2f6c5e8584c4a492578f4.jpg

Comment: Try to connect capacitor in series. For me it worked.

Comment: Hi user263983 I have thought about that... what size would you recommend trying first? It's been a long time since I had to calculate anything like this.

Comment: Change the line frequency. VFDs do just that.

Comment: I have a budget of about $100. Is there a suitable VFD kit in that range?

Comment: @Hearth The photo shows a motor with multiple taps for different speeds, also the post mentions multiple speed settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a continuously variable AC/DC 100W fan that is silent, very powerful and efficient using AC>DC>BLDC 3ph that has a high torque at low RPM which is basically a VFD controlled fan all in one.

Otherwise get a 6uF cap for a microwave oven from a commercial electrical parts store and put in series with the low speed switch position.  2.5uF might reduce the power too much if you only want 30% reduction in power.

FWIW [image]

Comment: Thanks Jasen and Tony. That's definitely a nice fan... 

Comment: I recently, reverse engineered it and modified the fan blade and wiring to become a pull fan instead of a push fan to reverse the 3 ph motor and sensors and slope of the blades.  Very nice fan design I got 2 for 160$  5400 cfm !

Comment: Just an update, tried a 5.6uF and that worked good except there is some visible vibration... noise level dropped from approx 70db to 61db. I'm ok to accept a little bit more noise for less vibration... I'm thinking maybe something around 7-8uF? But is the relationship linear or exponential?

Comment: 2.6uF 250V polypropylene capacitor in case it makes some difference. They have proper 400V motor soft start types as well that I could use..

Comment: Yes bigger caps exist, a 2 pole motor has more cogging impulse forces and less inertial damping at low speed, unlike a 3ph BLDC, a flywheel would help in theory

Comment: Just for future reference, added a 2.2uF in parallel and that was too big an increase in noise, so went back to 5.6uF overall. I will update on longevity in due course. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a 2.5uF capacitor in series with the blue wire, it will need to be a capacitor suited to mains operation.

If that's too slow use a larger capacitor or add more series capacitors in parallel with the first one.  if too fast use one with a lower capacitance.

Comment: Yes goto AliExpress.com and search for a VDF, I found at least one, 1.5Kw  for less then $60.00 plus shipping.

Comment: a capacitor is like $5 retail,  you porbably intended to post that on the main question.